# Count repetitions in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, count

> I know that similar questions have been asked and I have researched
>   many websites. I have tried to use some of the answers but my code is
>   still not working.
>
> I am going through a previous assignment to help build my knowledge
>   of Java. Please forgive any errors in my code, I am still learning
>   Java.
>
> Here is my question:

Implement a method count which, given an array of integer elements, returns another array containing the number of occurrences of each integer {0, ..., r} in the input array, where r is an integer to show the upper boundary of the integers that you need to count.

The returned array of counts will be of size r + 1, where the element at each index i corresponds to the number of occurrences of integer i (with i in {0, ..., r}).

Elements in the input array outside of the integer range from 0 to r can be ignored.

For example, given the input [0, 8, 1, 3, 1, 3, 10, 3] with r is 4, the output should be [1, 2, 0, 3, 0].

If the input array is null or of length 0, this will return null.

Space requirements: Method count should only use additional space for the count array.

Time requirements: The counts should be calculated in a single pass through the input array.

> Here is what I've done so far, it doesn't meet the requirements so I need help in order to find the right solution:

```
public static int[] count(int[] arr, int r) {
        int[] count = new int[r + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == j) {
                    count[i]++;

                }

            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it meet the requirements? What's the problem? Be specific.

Comment: @nicomp Index out of bounds + I think the logic is wrong

Comment: The value of r you are taking is wrong. In your example the value of r should be 10  because the numbers in the array are from {0 ... 10}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, but seems maybe a small bit is wrong.

```
int[] count = new int[r + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if( arr[i] <= r) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }
}
```

I think the above will work, if you think about it, each element of arr corresponds to an index in count as long as that index is within {0...r}, so we check that the value is within that range, then we increment the integer at that index within count.

Comment: @Pablo ...This, ideally, but as a minimal change to your original logic just fix `count[i]++` to `count[j]++`, because `j` is equal to `arr[i]` at that point. Probably what you wanted, just a typo.