# Calculates the number of occurrences of integers from the range * {0, ..., r} within a given array of integer elements

Tags: java, algorithm

For some reason, my solution is not complete. I got 83/100 from hidden spec tests.

What's wrong with my solution? There is probably a certain use case that I'm not thinking of.

Additional info:

> Implement a method count which, given an array of integer elements, returns another array containing the number of occurrences of each integer {0, ..., r} in the input array, where r is an integer to show the upper boundary of the integers that you need to count.
>
> The returned array of counts will be of size r + 1, where the element at each index i corresponds to the number of occurrences of integer i (with i in {0, ..., r}).
>
> Elements in the input array outside of the integer range from 0 to r can be ignored.
>
> For example, given the input [0, 8, 1, 3, 1, 3, 10, 3] with r is 4, the output should be [1, 2, 0, 3, 0].
>
> If the input array is null or of length 0, this will return null.
>
> Space requirements: Method count should only use additional space for the count array.
>
> Time requirements: The counts should be calculated in a single pass through the input array.

```
public class CountRepetitions {

    /**
     * Calculates the number of occurrences of integers from the range
     * {0, ..., r} within a given array of integer elements. Returns
     * the array of counts: a new array of integers of size r + 1, where the
     * element at index i denotes the number occurrences of elements equal
     * to i in the given input array (with i in {0, ..., r}).
     * If the input array is null or of length 0, this will return null.
     *
     * @param arr the array of integer elements to be counted.
     * @param r   the integer indicating the last element of the range.
     * @return a new array containing the number of occurrences of each
     * integer {0, ..., r} in the input array (index i has the
     * count of elements equal to i in the input array, with i
     * in {0, ..., r})
     */
    public static int[] count(int[] arr, int r) {
        // Exceptional cases
        // 1. If the input array is null or of length 0, this will return null.
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) return null;

        // Normal case
        int[] result = new int[r + 1];
        for (int x : arr) if (x >= 0 && x < r) result[x]++;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the value for r is bigger than you can allocate. It might be better to use a sparse storage?

Comment: The question says r is included in the range, so `x < r` should be `x <= r`. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: @kaya3 That was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if (x >= 0 && **x <= r**)

Also make sure to check for r >= 0.

Comment: Checking `r >= 0` is redundant, because it's implied by transitivity if the other two conditions are true. Since this is the only problem with the code, the question is off-topic as it's caused by a typo.

Comment: For example if you pass r == -2 to the method it will  try to allocate new int[-1] and fail

Comment: The question says *"The returned array of counts will be of size r + 1"* so if r = -2 is a possible input then the question itself is wrong, because it specifies that the method should return an array of length -1 in that case.

Comment: Well, I'm just paranoid :)  if (r < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("r is negative");

Comment: It looks like the online judge in question isn't that picky; based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53376837/12299000) to essentially the same question, you don't even need to check `x >= 0` to pass the test cases.

Comment: @kaya3 I do have to check for `x >= 0` otherwise the score will never be 100/100.

So the answer given in the topic you linked is not complete, just an intermediary solution.

Comment: @gforghieri Can you share the link?

Comment: @vivek_23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376667/count-repetitions-in-array-in-java/53376837#53376837

Comment: @gforghieri I mean the link where you are getting 83% as score. I think you are missing a check of `<= r` as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 its an internal web-app of the Delft University of Technology, similar to hackerrank or leetcode. External visitors don't have access.

Comment: @gforghieri Anyways, it looks like you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @kaya3 pointed out.

> The question says r is included in the range, so x < r should be **x <= r**.